# get only the M month from a date in php

Tags: php, date, drupal

i have this french date format :

> (Samedi, Aout 31, 2013)

and i want to get only the (M) of the date, for example for August i only want the (Aug)

PS : August in english = Aout  in french

Comment: @Fred-ii- i htried a lot of solutions in google and none of them are working
and the  reason is maybee because i'm using render function in drupal , so i decided to post this question to see more methods

Comment: Please include the code you've tried and what goes wrong.

Comment: I'm insulted that someone on StackOverflow actually went through the trouble of deleting my comment about the proper spelling of the word "Août" in French. Hmph~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $date = 'Samedi, Aout 31, 2013';
  $time = strtotime($date);
  $month_only = date('M', $time);
  echo $month_only;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stamp = strtotime("Samedi, Aout 31, 2013");
$month = strftime("%b", $stamp);
```

...or more concisely:

```
echo strftime("%b", strtotime("Samedi, Aout 31, 2013"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try:
explode(" ","Samedi, Aout 31, 2013")[1]